# EF4.x: Updating using detached entity without copying fields one by one

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, poco

I am using **EF 4.3, VS 2010, .net 4.0**. After google sometime, I did not get the answer, maybe most answers are for EF 5 and above.

I use db first to demo this question. The database sql:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_t] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
First I tried add new, like this:
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    T t = new T();
    t.ID = 1;
    t.Name = "a";
    TestDBEntities en = new TestDBEntities();
    //works no matter what the ID is,
    //and this is good
    en.AddToT(t);
    en.SaveChanges();
    MessageBox.Show("add");
}
```

Then tried update, my main goal is to pass an entity object, and directly update the entity with the same ID in database. If I copy the fields one by one, that will be OK. But if the entity has **many fields**(Here only 'Name' for demo), it will be time costing to write and maintain.

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    T t = new T();
    t.ID = 1;
    t.Name = "a";
    TestDBEntities en = new TestDBEntities();

    var old = en.T.First(m => m.ID == 1);
    //An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. 
    //The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.
    en.T.Attach(t);
    en.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(old, System.Data.EntityState.Modified);

    en.SaveChanges();
    MessageBox.Show("Update");
}
```

Comment: You can use tools like AutoMapper to map all the properties from one entity to another. Now the problem is, as per my knowledge there is no model binder for asp.net web forms application in .net 4.0. I found this tutorial for .net 4.5 where model binding is introduced in web forms applications. May be [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/03/28/tutorial-series-on-model-binding-with-asp-net-web-forms.aspx) helps. You can also write your own helper utility which will take POST parameters and bind them to a `Type`. Or may be search for one on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `DbContext.Entry` method that allows you to attach the object to back to the DbContext, was added in EF5+.

As @Nilesh mentioned, for easy model binding without copying each property you should use a tool like [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) or [ValueInjecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/).

With AutoMapper for example, you will simply do that:

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TModel t = new TModel();
    t.ID = 1;
    t.Name = "a";

    TestDBEntities en = new TestDBEntities();

    var entity = en.T.First(m => m.ID == 1);

    Mapper.Map<TModel, T>(t, entity);

    en.SaveChanges();
    MessageBox.Show("Update");
}
```

In case a more complex mapping is required, you can configure the mapping with `Mapper.CreateMap` method. Check the documentation for more examples.

Comment: Thank you, I also searched db.Entry and did not exist!